# plt.plot() runs infinitely when trying to plot pandas series or dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I've got a trouble when trying to run my jupyter notebook on another computer.

Here I want to plot some time series with `matplotlib.pyplot` module in order to overlay some points afterwards :

`plt.plot(data_df["timestamp"],data_df["sensor_00"])`

But then the interpreter/jupyter notebook keep running and only output the following information :

```
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x2a0f892a908>]
```

Yet the code is working if I use the dataframe's plot argument :

`data_df.set_index("timestamp")["sensor_00"].plot()`

Outputs:

[image: time series plot]

Just like I'd want ! I know i could just content myself with the dataframe's plotting method but I'll need the matplolib library for further visualizations.

This trouble happens with pandas objects and even when converting the values I want in numpy array, I just keep the program running and not displaying any output.

configuration on both computers :

- OS : windows 10 (same as the last computer I did run before).
- matplotlib version: 3.1.0 (updated on the computer but didn't work either)
- Pandas version : 0.24.2
- Python version : 3.7.3 on the new computer and 3.6.8 on the latter but I've tested on a 3.6.8 environment and still didn't work

Comment: Does `plt.show()` work?

Comment: I think you miss `plt.show()`.

Comment: It's not working with `plt.show()`, the notebook is just running even if I've put this line of code

Comment: There seems to be a contradiction. Either the notebook outputs something like `[<...>]`, ***or*** the notebook keeps running. Which one is it?

Comment: It does both. it outputs `[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x2a0f892a908>]` without the graph and the notebook keep on running

Comment: I don't think that is possible. `[<...>]` would be the last thing it does before going idle.

Comment: And yet it is the case! When I do it on jupyter notebook it does output the `[<..>]` thing but not the graph

Comment: Yes, so the output of `[<..>]` is fine, that's just the repr of the last thing you did in that. But it will stop running at that point. How exactly do you know that the kernel is still busy?

Comment: Well put it simply you can see a [*] on the left to
 your cell
 and a round spot winking on the upper right part of the notebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright after a few things I tried, my `"timestamp"` feature wasn't typed as a datetime object.
What I did to solve the problem :

- `data_df = data_df.set_index("timestamp")`
- `data_df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(data_df.index)`

Once the `timestamp` feature is now datetime object it plots fast just as it's supposed to do.